Здравствуйте! Может кто-нибудь подсказать как правильно обернуть тегами данный элемент?
При верстке макета появились затруднения написания кода для данного элемента.
Может кто-нибудь подсказать как правильно обернуть данный элемент?


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

что и во что ты хочешь обернуть?

надпись ОКОНАЧАНИЕ ЧЕРЕЗ думал обернуть в span.

сами ЦИФРЫ тоже span. или этот момент вообще через  js  будет лучше сделать

да, можешь обернуть в спаны или любые другие элементы.

Большое спасибо

Приведи пример кода, зачем гадать какие тэги тебе нужно вставлять?
